# Enable SSH on public IP

Tags: ssh, centos6.5

I've just taken the control of a server. This server worked in a private environment, in a VPN, accesible via a private IP. Now it's public and linked to a domain name. I can access SSH via the VPN using the private IP, but not via the domain name.

Which operations should I do?

It's a Centos 6.5 server.

Comment: What does the `Listen` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` say ?

Comment: I've two ListenAddress lines, both are commented.

Answer (score 2):

Your sshd is configured to use the defaults for `ListenAddress`, this means that it is listening on all available interfaces, so something else is causing your problem.

- To try and rule out DNS issues, try connecting direct to the public IP - what happens, what messages does ssh provide?
- Look at your iptables (firewall) configuration and determine if it is causing a problem, has the public IP address been blocked ?
- Is there an upstream device that is blocking access ?

Comment: 1. `Connection timedout`   ////    
2. In `iptables.old` I've `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` so it should be fine. There's not iptables (without .old)  ////    
3. Don't think so.

Comment: Maybe it can be relevant, I've the same problem with FTP (tough `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT` is missing in iptables.old.

Comment: What you need to do now, is learn what Connection timeout means, then apply that information to your problem. Yous hould also learn how to find out what he current state of iptables in the kernel is,